# Second lowest value of property in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database where I need to find the second lowest value of time which is one of the property of relationship. Can anyone help me with how to find the second lowest value. `min()` function can be used to find the minimum value but I am confused on how to find the second lowest value.

Edit 1:
I am attaching the snapshot of the graph below

[image: Graph snap]

Also I am giving the link data being fetched from the graph below.

[Graph Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pz4nZ84sGfX5uVkgxz1ZX4ZIexTqta1Fgesnd8dDY60/edit?usp=sharing)

What I am trying to do here is fetch the next action done by this particular 'msisdn' after doing the 'TT' action. Please find the query below for the same.

Query:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) where r.ActionType='TT' and n.msisdn='258846417980'
with n,min(r.ActionTime) as min
MATCH (n)-[r]->(k)
where r.ActionTime=min and r.ActionType='TT' 
MATCH (n)-[rout]->() where rout.ActionTime>min
WITH n,collect( distinct
       { relationship:type(rout), 
         node: endNode(rout), rType: rout.ActionType, rTime: rout.ActionTime, rChannel: rout.ContactChannel
       }) AS outgoing
RETURN { node: n, outgoing: outgoing } AS result limit 5;
```

Above query will give all the actions done by the particular 'msisdn' after doing the action 'TT'. Please help me in finding just the next action based on the 'ActionTime'

Edit2 : Attaching the Graph Data for 5 msisdn (in actual there are thousands). I want to find the very next action (relationship) of all the msisdn after min ActionTime of 'TT'.
[Graph Data Modified](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E7cpMuV3WTbcdBspTHbDHLXkBgh-Fe_oHLHK0MBQr7o/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: If there are multiple nodes with the same min value, do you want that min value (since the second lowest has the same value), or do you want the next lowest distinct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you exactly want, but this query should return for the specified `msisdn`, in `ActionTime` order, an `outgoing` collection with info on the next 5 relationships whose `ActionTime` values are greater than the minimum `TT` `ActionTime` value:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) WHERE r.ActionType='TT' AND n.msisdn='258846417980'
with n, MIN(r.ActionTime) as min
MATCH (n)-[rout]->() WHERE rout.ActionTime > min
WITH n, rout
ORDER BY rout.ActionTime
LIMIT 5
RETURN {
    node: n,
    outgoing: COLLECT(
      { relationship: TYPE(rout), 
        node: ENDNODE(rout),
        rType: rout.ActionType,
        rTime: rout.ActionTime,
        rChannel: rout.ContactChannel
      })
  } AS result;
```

[EDITED 4 times]

To get info on the very next relationship for nodes with five `msisdn` values, and get the unique `ActionTypes` associated with each node:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.msisdn IN ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) WHERE r.ActionType='TT'
WITH n, MIN(r.ActionTime) as min
MATCH (n)-[rout]->() WHERE rout.ActionTime > min
WITH n, rout
ORDER BY rout.ActionTime
WITH n, COLLECT(rout) AS rs
WITH n, rs[0] AS r,
  REDUCE(s = [], x IN rs |
    CASE WHEN x.ActionType IN s THEN s ELSE s + x.ActionType END) AS types
RETURN {
    node: n,
    outgoing: {
      relationship: TYPE(r), 
      node: ENDNODE(r),
      rType: r.ActionType,
      rTime: r.ActionTime,
      rChannel: r.ContactChannel
    },
    actionTypes: types
  } AS result;
```

Hint: You should actually pass the collection of `msisdn` values as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/) instead of harcoding it every time.

Comment: What I actually need is the very next action among the actions which happened after the min action time of 'TT'. I don't want the next 5 actions. Can you help me find the very next action (relationship) that happened after the min TT ActionTime.

Comment: Thanks it works for single msisdn. In my actual dataset, there are thousands of such msisdn for whom I want to get the very next relationship. Can you guide me how to achieve that. If I use Limit 1 at last, only one msisdn will come in result.

Comment: Please see my edited question and modified graph data as well.

Comment: Any idea how to make this happen for multiple msisdn?

Comment: I can't pass msisdn(node) as parameters. All the nodes are already created in neo4j database and I need to run this query on all the existing nodes present in db. I tried below query but this also returned single msisdn

Comment: MATCH (n)-[r]->(k)
with n, collect(n.msisdn) as list 
Match (n) WHERE n.msisdn IN list
MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) WHERE r.ActionType='TT'
WITH n, MIN(r.ActionTime) as min
MATCH (n)-[rout]->() WHERE rout.ActionTime > min
WITH n, rout
ORDER BY rout.ActionTime
RETURN {
    node: n,
    outgoing:
      { relationship: TYPE(rout), 
        node: ENDNODE(rout),
        rType: rout.ActionType,
        rTime: rout.ActionTime,
        rChannel: rout.ContactChannel
      }
  } AS result
LIMIT 1;

Comment: Even this query gives only one msisdn.
MATCH (n) with n, collect(n.msisdn) as list 
Match (n) WHERE n.msisdn IN list
MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) WHERE r.ActionType='TT' 
WITH n, MIN(r.ActionTime) as min 
MATCH (n)-[rout]->() 
WHERE rout.ActionTime > min 
WITH n, rout ORDER BY rout.ActionTime 
RETURN { node: n, outgoing: { relationship: TYPE(rout), node: ENDNODE(rout), rType: rout.ActionType, rTime: rout.ActionTime, rChannel: rout.ContactChannel } } AS result LIMIT 1;

Comment: Try my re-edited answer. Also, you would not pass nodes as parameters (that's not possible). Instead, you would pass a collection of `msisdn` string values (like `[258846417980, 258846417981]`). For example: `MATCH (n) WHERE n.msisdn IN $idlist`, where the value of `$idlist` would be `[258846417980, 258846417981]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! Your re-edited answer works fine. Typo, msisdn is one of the property of node (not node).

Comment: I got another more complex related issue. Is it feasible to ask you directly or do I need to post a separate question.

Comment: Also is it possible to get the count of all the unique r.ActionType in the same query?

Comment: It might be possible, but it would make the query overly complex.

Comment: I got only two option, either iterate in java the resultset of query to find the count of all the unique r.ActionType or I get it from the query itself, I guess getting it from query can be more efficient even if query is complex, can u help how the query will be if I need to get it done from query. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question completely, you can use a query like the following to get se second lowest value of a property in a relationship:

```
MATCH (:Node)-[r:REL_TYPE]->()
WITH r ORDER BY r.property
RETURN collect(distinct r.property)[1] AS secondLowestValue
```

Basically I'm sorting the `r` relationships by `r.property` in ascending order. Then I'm storing the ordered property values in an array and returning the second element. That is: returning the second lowest value.

As a second alternative you can use [ORDER BY](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/order-by/), [SKIP](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/skip/) and [LIMIT](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/limit/) to achieve the same result (thanks to @stdob--).

```
MATCH (:Node)-[r:REL_TYPE]->()
WITH distinct r.property as property ORDER BY r.property SKIP 1 LIMIT 1
RETURN property
```

I have tested both solutions in a small data set with 12 nodes and 6 relationships. The [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) shows that the first solution executes 47 db hints, while de second solution executes 37 db hints. That is: considering this simple metric the second solution has a best performance for this data set.

Comment: I think that sorting, limit and skip is more effective.

Comment: @stdob-- I agree. I have updated the answer, take a look.

Comment: I compared these two queries on 100 nodes and 10 thousand relationships: 40201 db hints (collect) and 20201 db hints (skip/limit). But your first variant of the query is suitable for cases where you need to find the required value in nested queries (for example, in a unwind), and when the skip / limit is truncated the entire query,

Comment: @Bruno Edited my question, my issue is not getting resolved, what I thought that If I will be able to find the second lowest time, then in my query I will put
rout.ActionTime=SecondLowestTime. 
Please guide where I am going wrong or how shall I modify my query

Comment: @palpras this is not enough? `MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) where r.ActionType= 'TT' and n.msisdn = '258846417980'
WITH r SKIP 1 LIMIT 1 ORDER BY r.actionTime
RETURN r`

Comment: @BrunoPeres Above query cannot be executed as order by is placed wrongly in the query. Also what I need is there will be multiple actions of 'TT' itself so I need to find the min of 'TT' action first then I need to find the next action done by the particular 'msisdn'. Also actual dataset is for millions of such 'msisdn', I am trying to find for one so that later on I can get next actions of millions of 'msisdn'

Comment: @palpras I don't know if I completely understood, but what you think about it? `MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) where r.ActionType='TT' and n.msisdn='258846417980'
WITH n, r.ActionTime as minTime order by minTime
WITH n, collect(minTime)[1] AS SecondLowestTime
MATCH (n)-[rout]->() where rout.ActionTime= SecondLowestTime
WITH n,collect( distinct
       { relationship:type(rout), 
         node: endNode(rout), rType: rout.ActionType, rTime: rout.ActionTime, rChannel: rout.ContactChannel
       }) AS outgoing
RETURN { node: n, outgoing: outgoing } AS result limit 5;`

Comment: @BrunoPeres The above query does not give any result at all as you have already filtered the dataset with SecondLowestTime. The "WITH n, collect(minTime)[1] AS SecondLowestTime" part of the query filters the dataset resulting is no result at all. What I actually want is to first find the min time of action 'TT' (as there can be multiple action of 'TT') then find the very next action done after 'TT'

Comment: @BrunoPeres Is there any way to declare the variable "SecondLowest" in below query. If yes, then issue may get resolved.

Comment: Query: MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) where r.ActionType='TT' and n.msisdn='258846417980' with n,min(r.ActionTime) as min,r ORDER BY r.ActionTime, collect(distinct r.ActionTime)[1] in SecondLowest MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) where r.ActionTime=min and r.ActionType='TT' MATCH (n)-[rout]->() where rout.ActionTime=SecondLowest WITH n,collect( distinct { relationship:type(rout), node: endNode(rout), rType: rout.ActionType, rTime: rout.ActionTime, rChannel: rout.ContactChannel }) AS outgoing RETURN { node: n, outgoing: outgoing } AS result limit 5;

Comment: Hi @palpras the above query that you posted solved your issue?

Comment: @BrunoPeres No the above query cannot be executed as the variable SecondLowest is not defined. Is there any way to define the variable?
collect(distinct r.ActionTime)[1] in SecondLowest -- this part shows error

Comment: @palpras can you post here the exact error message that you are receiving?

Comment: @palpras I think you are having problems when index 2 is null. You can try using [coalesce function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce) that returns the first non-null value in the given list of expressions. That is: use `WITH n, coalesce(collect(minTime)[1], collect(minTime)[0]) AS SecondLowestTime`. If index 1 is null, index 0 will be used.

Comment: @BrunoPeres 
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
Variable `SecondLowest` not defined (line 3, column 38 (offset: 165))
"collect(distinct r.ActionTime)[1] in SecondLowest "
                                      ^

Comment: @palpras you have a typo error. In this case the operator is `AS` and not `in`. Use `collect(distinct r.ActionTime)[1] as SecondLowest`.

Comment: @BrunoPeres It is not typo, I cannot use "AS" here, only option is to use in. If I try using as then will get the error - 'mismatched input'.

Comment: @BrunoPeres My problem is I also need to find the min of 'TT' first which you missed in your query, can u modify your query which also includes the this part
MATCH (n)-[r]->(k)
where r.ActionTime=min and r.ActionType='TT'

Comment: @BrunoPeres What I actually need is the lowest action time among the actions which happened after the min action time of 'TT'. Hope you are able to understand my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Below query completely answers my question.

```
MATCH (n) with n, collect(n.msisdn) as list 
Match (n) WHERE n.msisdn IN list
MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) WHERE r.ActionType='TT'
WITH n, MIN(r.ActionTime) as min
MATCH (n)-[rout]->() WHERE rout.ActionTime > min
WITH n, rout
ORDER BY rout.ActionTime
WITH n, COLLECT(rout)[0] AS r
RETURN {
node: n,
outgoing:
  { relationship: TYPE(r), 
    node: ENDNODE(r),
    rType: r.ActionType,
    rTime: r.ActionTime,
    rChannel: r.ContactChannel
  }
} AS result;
```